# eOS Juno : Scale at 1 but display too big yet

Tags: release-juno, gtk

I have Elementary OS Juno and I wanted to change the scale because all was too little. So I went to "Display" in settings and I double pixels. but now, it's too big and when I try to go back with "automatic" or "little DPI" (I'm not sure about the translation, I have the french version of eOS), the scale down but it's too big.
I tried :

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
```

but nothing change, and when I get scaling factor, it's 1. How can I down the scale ?

Note : It's on my laptop, a 1980x1080.

Note 2 : When I connect my laptop to an external screen (1980x1080), all is good.

Please help me,
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by leaving the scaling factor at default value and increased font size with [elementary-tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks). Gnome (GTK) has some problems with fractional scaling, so things are either too big or too small.

Bear in mind that some apps may still look really big, or small. Especially QT or Java apps.